# Bought an Ubuntu Notebook - Pre Installed - Encrypted

Tags: encryption

Apologies if this extremely easy or not related as this is my first time using Ubuntu.

I bought a notebook with Ubuntu Pre installed, however, I´m having a hard time to do the first log in.

You may find attached that when following the "usual" steps of boot, the system will jump me into a screen where it requires a password that I wasn´t informed:

[image: Password Screen]

I´ve already contacted the store to see if they can help me. But maybe you can help me!

Thanks,

Comment: The screen shown is a normal Grub boot loaded. Either wait up to 30 seconds without touching anything or press Enter with `Ubuntu` selected. If it THEN asks you for a password, was it bought new, used or as a display unit?

Comment: Could you show this login screen?

Comment: I thought the login screen had loaded earlier, I´ve update the post. Tks!

Comment: You have two options: (1) wait for the store that sold you the machine to supply the password (2) reinstall Ubuntu, wiping out everything on the storage device. There is no (realistic) way to reverse out a disk encryption password ... otherwise there'd be little point in encrypting disks 

Comment: Thanks guys, they've given me a prompt answer.